# Can a large file be compressed before upload from UI in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, angular7, angular8

Is there any way to compress a file before upload from front end? I have a very large file to upload which takes so much of time. I am looking for a way to reduce the time for the upload.

Comment: Mostly My files will be excel file.

Comment: This question is not actually related to angular. It'd be nice if you could frame it properly so that other people can more easily find a solution to the same problem.
Also, it is possible that your browser will compress the upload transparently at the HTTP level (`Content-Encoding: gzip`) if the file is larger than a threshold that the browser vendor has determined to make compression effective. Have you tested that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using html-to-image plugin to convert image to lower quality and then apply upload as you are doing.

> npm install --save html-to-image

You can try other htmlToImage method, up to you. What I have used is below:

```
htmlToImage.toJpeg(node, { quality: 0.95 }).then(function (dataUrl) {
  let link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = "page" + '.jpeg';
  link.classList.add("specialanchor")
  link.href = dataUrl;
  link.click();
}).catch(function (error) {
  // console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
});
```

To learn more:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image

Answer (score -1):

There are a handful of file compression libraries, like [wasm-flate](https://github.com/drbh/wasm-flate) or [JSCompress](https://jscompress.com/). 
If you Google [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20webassembly%20file%20compression), you should get quite a few hits that can help you with file compression in the browser.